# How to turn off laptop sound when mail received

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

Every time I receive a mail my laptop makes a sound to signify this. How can I turn this off?

I've tried turning off the sound scheme in control panel -> sounds :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn the sound off in Outlook.

**Tools > Options > Preferences > E-mail Options > Advanced E-mail Options**

Then in the "When new items arrive in my Inbox" section, clear the

> Play a sound

option:

[image]

Comment: thanks, this also helped : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-sound-effects-HP010355558.aspx